# Simplest way to replace (\n) with (" ") in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

In a plain text file, I am trying to get from

```
 Item 1
 Item 2
```

to

```
 "Item 1" "Item 2"
```

I tried using the `tr` command (`cat FILE.txt | tr "\n" "\" \""`),
but that did not work.
I also tried using `cat FILE.txt | tr '\n' '\" \"'`, but again, no avail.

Can anyone help me do it?

---

Also, as a bonus question, what is the easiest way to get the first double quote?
With my method, if I get it to work, I will end up with:

```
Item 1" "Item 2"
```

P.S. Thanks Jorengarenar for helping me with the edit.

Comment: Also make sure that there really is a \n and not a \r\n (Windows) or an \r (Mac).

Comment: Thanks. It is an actual \n, as in, if I run the command (tr "\n" " "), it replaces the new lines with spaces. The brackets are just meant to highlight the code, of course.

Comment: @I.P To be clear: you mean actual newline characters, not backslashes followed by the letter "n", right?

Comment: Well, in the text document, these are just new line, as one would expect. However, when I run the code, I am using the backslashes, followed by the letter n. That does work.

Comment: @I.P Some programs, like `tr`, will translate `\n` into newline in at least some situations; but it's best to be clear that while `\n` may be used to represent newline in some situations, it's not actually a newline.

Comment: The arguments to `tr` are individual characters, there is no way to replace a character with a string of more than one character with `tr`. This is a common beginner FAQ.

Comment: More generally, almost all shell utilities work better with line-oriented input, so this really begs the question why you want to transfer a perfectly well-organized text file into a somewhat arcane format.

Comment: @tripleee to pipe a bunch of files into an other program. In this case, the other program likes it like that more :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility would be to use awk.

```
awk '{ printf " " "\""$0"\"" }' FILE
```

For the bonus question, just remove the second quote after the $0 variable.

```
awk '{ printf " " "\""$0"" }' FILE
```

If you want another delimiter, you can change the first argument to whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
awk '{printf spacer "\"" $0 "\""; spacer=" "} END {print ""}' FILE.txt
```

Explanation: for each line, this prints a spacer (which is initially empty), a literal double-quote, the original line (not including its terminating newline), and another literal double-quote. Then, it sets `spacer` to a single space, so that for all but the first line there'll be a space printed before it. `printf` doesn't add a newline, so all of this gets printed as a single long line. But at the end, we need to add a final newline, which a normal `print` takes care of.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the file itself, one way using `ed`:

```sh
ed -s file.txt <<'EOF'
1,$ s/^/"/
1,$ s/$/" /
1,$ j
w
EOF
```

First add a double quote to the beginning of every line, then a double quote and space to the end, and finally **j**oin all the lines into one and **w**rite the changed file back to disk.

Comment: Thank one worked as well :) Made myself even a little script, for future use. :) Thanks a bunch to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

In two steps:
1.`cat FILE.txt |  tr '\n' ' '`
2.`sed  -E 's:([a-zA-Z0-9]+):"\1":g' FILE.txt`

Comment: Seems also interesting. Thanks.

Comment: Forgot to mention -i flag in sed for inline editing of FILE.txt :)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU utils):

```
sed 's/.*/"&"/' file | paste -sd\
```

or:

```
sed 's/.*/\\"&\\"/' file | xargs
```

N.B. The `-d` option in paste is a backslash followed by a space for the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

or leverage awk

```
[gmn]awk -v RS='^$' 'gsub(/^|\n$/,"\"")+gsub(/\n/,"\" \"")'
```

or

```
[gmn]awk -v RS='' 'gsub(/^|\n?$/,"\"")+gsub(/\n/,"\" \"")'
```

not as elegant of a one-liner as i hoped for

third version feels more elegant, but one extra space created at the tail end :

```
[gmn]awk -v ORS=' ' 'gsub(/^|$/,"\"")'
```

which can be rectified by one extra sed, which defeats the elegance :

```
[gmn]awk -v ORS=' ' 'gsub(/^|$/,"\"")' | gsed -z 's/.$//'
```