# Remove first two lines, last two lines and space from file and add quotes on each line and replace newline with commas in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, scripting

I have to input.txt file which needs to be formatted by shell script with following condition

1. remove first two lines and
   last two lines
2. remove all spaces in each
   lines(each line have two spaces at
   beginning and one space at end)
3. Each line should be within single
   quotes(' ')
4. At last replace newline($) with
   commas.

(original)
**input.txt**

```
 sql
--------
  Abce
  Bca
  Efr
-------
Row (3)
```

Desired output file

***output.txt***

```
'Abce','Bca','Efr'
```

I have tried using following commands

```
Sed -i 1,2d input.txt > input.txt
Sed "$(( $(wc -l <input.txt) -2+1)), $ d" Input.txt > input.txt
Sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/, /g' input.txt > output.txt
```

But i get blank output.txt

Comment: [This old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69266071/9952196) of mine can be a starting point.

Comment: Thanks, new to stackoverflow and shell scripting

Comment: `Sed` is not a valid command. Please take care to provide a [mre]

Comment: Avoid `sed -i`.  And `sed -i input.file > input.file` is .... well, very strange.  The point of `sed -i` (if indeed it has one) is to modify the file "in-place" and not produce any output.  The point of `> file` is to write the output to the file.  (But `sed -i` does not produce output!).  `sed -i` does not actually modify the file directly, but works on a copy.  But the shell is going to truncate the file (discard all the data in it) before `sed` begins, so you'll end up with nothing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not a one liner but works

```
sed "s/^ */\'/;s/\$/\',/;1,2d;N;\$!P;\$!D;\$d"  | sed ' H;1h;$!d;x;s/\n//g;s/,$//'
```

Explanation:

`s/^ */\'/;s/\$/\',/`    ---> Adds single quotes and comma

`N;$!P;$!D;$d` ---> Deletes last two lines

`H;1h;$!d;x;s/\n//g;s/,$//'` ---> Loads entire file and merge all lines and remove last comma

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` program. Written and tested in GNU `awk`, should work with any version.

```
awk -v s1="'" -v lines="$(wc -l < Input_file)" '
BEGIN{ OFS="," }
FNR==(lines-1) {
  print val
  exit
}
FNR>2{
  sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"")
  val=(val?val OFS:"") (s1 $0 s1)
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code, this is only for explanation purposes.

```
awk -v s1="'" -v lines="$(wc -l < Input_file)" '  ##Starting awk program, setting s1 variable to ' and creating lines which has total number of lines in it, using wc -l command on Input_file file.
BEGIN{ OFS="," }                                ##Setting OFS to comma in BEGIN section of this program.
FNR==(lines-1) {                                ##Checking condition if its 2nd last line of Input_file.
  print val                                     ##Then printing val here.
  exit                                          ##exiting from program from here.
}
FNR>2{                                          ##Checking condition if FNR is greater than 2 then do following.
  sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"")                       ##Substituting initial spaces with NULL here.
  val=(val?val OFS:"") (s1 $0 s1)               ##Creating val which has ' current line ' in it and keep adding it in val.
}
' Input_file                                    ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: not working on macOS, because of `wc`

Comment: @Fravadona, it worked fine for me in rhel-7, I don't have Mac with me so can't test it.

Comment: the output of `wc -l < Input_file` is prepended with space characters on BSD; `echo $(wc -l < Input_file)` would be more portable

Comment: Just quote the output of wc and it'll work as-is: `lines="$(wc -l < Input_file)"` because the usage of `lines` as a number in your script, `lines-1`, will strip the leading blanks during the standard string->number conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try the following:

```
mapfile -t ary < <(tail -n +3 input.txt | head -n -2 | sed -E "s/^[[:blank:]]*/'/; s/[[:blank:]]*$/'/")
(IFS=,; echo "${ary[*]}")
```

- `tail -n +3` outputs lines after the 3rd line, inclusive.
- `head -n -2` outputs lines excluding the last 2 lines.
- `sed -E "s/^[[:blank:]]*/'/"` removes leading whitespaces and prepends
  a single quote.
- Similarly the sed command `"s/[[:blank:]]*$/'/"` removes trailing
  whitespaces and appends a single quote.
- The syntax <(command ..) is a process substitution and the
  output of the commands within the parentheses is fed to the `mapfile`
  via the redirect.
- `mapfile -t ary` reads lines from the standard input into the array
  variable named `ary`.
- `echo "${ary[*]}"` expands to a single string with the contents of
  the array `ary` separated by the value of `IFS`, which is just assigned
  to a comma.
- The assignment of `IFS` and the array expansion are enclosed with
  parentheses to be executed in the subshell. This prevents the `IFS`
  to be modified in the current process.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the input is small enough to fit in memory:

```
$ awk '
    NR>4 { gsub(/^ *| *$/,"\047",p2); out=out sep p2; sep="," }
    { p2=p1; p1=$0 }
    END { print out }
' input.txt
'Abce','Bca','Efr'
```

Otherwise:

```
$ awk '
    NR>4 { gsub(/^ *| *$/,"\047",p2); printf "%s%s", sep, p2; sep="," }
    { p2=p1; p1=$0 }
    END { print "" }
' input.txt
'Abce','Bca','Efr'
```

Either script will work using any awk in any shell on every Unix box.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '1,2d;$!H;$!d;x;s/^\s*(.*)\s*$/'\''\1'\''/mg;s/\n[^\n]*$//;y/\n/,/' file
```

Delete the first two lines.

Append each line to the hold space, except for the last (this means the second from last line will still be present - see later).

Delete all lines except for the last.

Swap to the hold space.

Remove all spaces either side of the words on each line and surround those words by single quotes.

Remove the last line and its newline.

Replace all newlines by commas.

Answer (score 0):

The first `sed -i` overwrites `input.txt` with an empty file. You can't write output back to the file you are reading, and `sed -i` does not produce any output anyway.

The minimal fix is to take out the `-i` and string together the commands into a pipeline; but of course, `sed` allows you to combine the commands into a single script.

```
len=$(wc -l <input.txt)
sed -e '1,2d' -e "$((len - 3))"',$d' \
    -e ':a' \
    -e 's/^  \(.*\) $/'"'\\1'/" \
    -e N -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n/, /g' input.txt >output.txt
```

(Untested; if your `sed` does not allow multiple `-e` options, needs refactoring to use a single string with semicolons or newlines between the commands.)

This is hard to write and debug and brittle because of the ways you have to combine the quoting features of the shell with the requirements of `sed` and this particular script, but also more inherently because `sed` is a terse and obscure language.

A much more legible and maintainable solution is to switch to Awk, which allows you to express the logic in more human terms, and avoid having to pull in support from the shell for simple tasks like arithmetic and string formatting.

```
awk 'FNR > 2 { sub(/^  /, ""); sub(/ $/, "");
    a[++i] = sprintf("\047%s\047,", $0); }
    END { for(j=1; j < i-1; ++j) printf "%s", a[j] }' input.txt >output.txt
```

This literally replaces all newlines with commas; perhaps you would in fact like to print a newline instead of the comma on the last line?

```
awk 'FNR > 2 { sub(/^  /, ""); sub(/ $/, "");
    a[++i] = sprintf("%s\047%s\047", sep, $0); sep="," }
    END { for(j=1; j < i-1; ++j) printf "%s", a[j]; printf "\n" }' input.txt >output.txt
```

If the input file is really large, you might want to refactor this to not keep all the lines in memory.  The array `a` collects the formatted output and we print all its elements except the last two in the `END` block.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post a sed solution which is rather light.

```sh
sed '$d' input.txt | sed "\$d; 1,2d; s/^\s*\|\s*$/'/g" | paste -sd ',' > output.txt
```

- `$d` Remove last line with first sed
- `\$d` Remove the last line. `$` escaped with backslash as we are within double-quotes.
- `1,2d` Remove the first two lines.
- `s/^\s*\|\s*$/'/g` Replace all leading and trailing whitespace with single quotes.
- Use `paste` to concatenate to a single, comma delimited  strings.

If we know that the relevant lines always start with two spaces, then it can even be simplified further.

```sh
sed -n "s/\s*$/'/; s/^  /'/p" input.txt | paste -sd ',' > output.txt
```

- `-n` suppress printing lines unless told to
- `s/\s*$/'/` replace trailing whitespace with single quotes
- `s/^  /'/p` replace two leading spaces and print lines that match
- `paste` to concat

---

Then an awk solution:

```sh
awk -v i=1 -v q=\' 'FNR>2 {
    gsub(/^[[:space:]]*|[[:space:]]*$/, q)
    a[i++]=$0
} END {
    for(i=1; i<=length(a)-3; i++)
        printf "%s,", a[i]
    print a[i++]
}' input.txt > output.txt
```

- `-v i=1` create an awk variable starting at one
- `-v q=\'` create an awk variable for the single quote character
- `FNR>2 { ...` tells it to only process line 3+
- `gsub(/^[[:space:]]*|[[:space:]]*$/, q)` substitute leading and trailing whitespace with single quotes
- `a[i++]=$0` add line to array
- `END { ...` Process the rest after reaching end of file
- `for(i=1; i<=length(a)-3; i++)` take the length of the array but subtract three -- representing the last three lines
- `printf "%s,", a[i]` print all but last three entries comma delimited
- `print a[i++]` print next entry and complete the script (skipping the last two entries)

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -E '
/^-+$/,/^-+$/!d
//d
s/^[[:space:]]*|[[:space:]]*$/'\''/g
' input.txt |
paste -sd ,
```

- This uses a trick that doesn't work on all sed implementations, to print the lines between two patterns (the dashes in this case), *excluding* those patterns.
- On the plus side if the `----` pattern is at a different line number, it still works. Down side is it breaks, if that pattern (a line containing only dashes) occurs an odd number of times (ie. not in pairs, that wrap the lines you want).
- Then sub line start and end (including white space) with single quotes.
- Finally pipe to `paste` to sub the new lines with commas, excluding a trailing comma.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed "1,2d; /-/,$ d; s/\s\+//;s/.*/'&'/" input_file | sed -z 's/\n/,/g;s/,$/\n/'
'Abce','Bca','Efr'
```